# Problem with Line spacing in wysiwyg editor in WP 3.5.1

Tags: tinymce, editor, wysiwyg, post-editor

Since updating to 3.5.1, I can no longer get single line breaks in the WYSIWYG editor.  I used to be able to shift-return for a line break and return for a paragraph break.  But now all lines have double spacing.  Hitting "delete" at the beginning of the line does not help.

I can of course fix this by switching out of WYSWYG mode, but this makes no sense to me.  I tried replacing the WP-ADMIN folder with a fresh copy, no change.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A "workaround" that I found which made it work for me today is to add:

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

to the end of wp-config.php

Comment: Please explain why this should work.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem with some old plugins/themes and "recent versions" of Wordpress.  For more info, read this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/editor-stuck-in-html

Answer (score 0):

On windows, I use `ALT + SHIFT + ENTER`, for Mac I think that would be `OPTION + SHIFT + RETURN`